# How to remove the city label in openlayer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a WMS layer like this

```
var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'basic,clabel,ctylabel,statelabel', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: .7}
            );
```

How do I remove ctylabel or statelabel from this wms layer?

I just want to remove the labels on the fly. Not at the creation of this layer. When user interact with the map I want to add/remove some labels like ctylabel or statelabel. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created the layer already and want to remove the labels later:

```
wms_layer.mergeNewParams({LAYERS: 'basic,clabel'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to do it dynamcially, here are two ways. The first one goes like this:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'basic,clabel,ctylabel,statelabel', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: true, opacity: .7}
            );    
layer.events.register('click', layer, function (evt) {
        map.removeLayer(layer)
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('OpenLayers WMS',
        'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
         {layers: 'basic', transparent: true},
         {isBaseLayer: true, opacity: .7}
         );
         map.addLayer(layer);    
    });
```

Since the WMS sends a raster image of the requested map based upon the request, you cannot remove some layers from the WMS layer after it has been requested. What you have to do is remove the layer from the map and request it again with new parameters.

A nice workaround of this problem could look the following:

```
basicLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'basic', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: true, opacity: .7}
            );    
labelsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'OpenLayers WMS',
            'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
            {layers: 'clabel,ctylabel,statelabel', transparent: true},
            {isBaseLayer: true, opacity: .7}
            );  
map.events.register('click', map, function (evt) {
    map.removeLayer(labelsLayer);
});
```

Basically, you now have two layers. One of them contains the features and the other all the labels. If you click in the map, the labels layer is removed.

Both ways are tested and working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to remove the labels on the fly. Not at the creation of that layer. When user interact with the map i want to add/remove some labels like ctylabel or statelabel. How to ad or remove this on the fly?